# Update index of a list after deleting a row

Tags: android, list, android-listview, indexing

How can I update the index of a list of 5 rows, after deletion of the 2nd row?

Comment: Just remove the second item from the dataset of your listview, and call notifyDataSetChanged on your listview adapter.

Comment: If you need more detailed answer, please add details to your query.

Comment: Thats pleasure :)  Posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the second item from the dataset of your listview, and call notifyDataSetChanged on your listview adapter like -

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```